# Advantages of using EF core in memory database provider for unit testing of asp.net core application

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, in-memory-database, ef-core-2.0

Is entity framework core in memory database provider replace moq ? What should i use for unit testing in my asp.net core application. I am using asp.net core mvc and ef core 2.0.

Comment: `In memory database` is not a replacement of MOQ; both are two different features. MOQ is used for mocking the 3rd party objects or objects beyond the scope of unit test so that unit tests can be written for well effective smaller unit. And `In memory database` is used to validate the data access APIs against the data which one arrange for a unit test.  It is designed for testing purposes only.

Comment: You may find the [Testing in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/) docs interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`In memory database` is not a replacement of `MOQ`; both are two different features.

`MOQ` is used for mocking the 3rd party objects or objects beyond the scope of unit test so that unit tests can be written for well effective smaller unit.

While `In memory database` is used to validate the data access APIs against the data which one arrange for a unit test. It is designed for testing purposes only.

Comment: Is it good practice using both for unit test in same application ?

Comment: Yes, both can be used in same application.